# copying multiple records from one table to another (same structure) (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

So here is what I am trying to do:

Copy every record from one table where the item_id is that of which is in my array.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO archive_items_tb SELECT * FROM item_bank_tb WHERE item_id IN(" . implode(',', $questions) . ")");
```

`$questions` is an array of question ids, parsed to this function.

mysql does not like my attempt, so can somebody please direct to the correct syntax.

thanks

Comment: did you try to make a loop where for each number($i) in the array select * from item_bank_tbh where item_id = $i and then insert that row into archive_items_tb...

Comment: "mysql does not like my attempt" tells us nothing, post the error you receive. Are you even sure that your $questions is even an array and that it has any elements?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your sub-select in parenthesis.  Also, as a note, make sure you escape the values in your `$questions` array.

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO archive_items_tb
(
    SELECT * FROM item_bank_tb
    WHERE item_id IN (" . implode(',', $questions) . ")
)";

mysql_query($query);
```